# Type hinting Vue 3 global properties from local dependency

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I'm currently developing a local dependency for a collection of application that will be using the same server/APIs. I have managed to successfully inject a global property into Vue using the following.

```
const BasePlugin = {
    install: (app: App, options: {
        domain: boolean
    }) => {
        app.config.globalProperties.$library = API
    }
  }
```

I am trying to provide the interface to typescript/virtual using the following code inside the dependency

```
declare module '@vue/runtime-core' {
  interface ComponentCustomProperties {
    $library: typeof API;
  }
}
```

How ever this doesn't seem to work :(

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. How doesn't it work for you?